# Javascript function to output string with line breaks to create a right triangle

Tags: javascript

I am taking an intro to Javascript class and am stuck on an assignment.

Write a function called drawTriangle that returns the following string. Feel free to debug-print using console.log, but make sure that the function actually returns a string.

Note that in a string, the character for a carriage return (the equivalent of hitting the “Enter” or “Return” key) is “\n”.

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
```

My initial thought was that I would use a loop to populate an array (with the hope of finding a way to output the array as a string with line breaks) but I am stuck at that point and not sure how to move forward (or if I am going in the wrong direction).

My current script is as follows:

```
function triangle(number) {
    var triElements = [];
    var pound = '#';
    var rightTriangle = '';
    var lineBreak = '\n';
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var rightTriangle = rightTriangle.concat(pound)
        triElements.push(rightTriangle);
    }
    return triElements;
}

console.log(triangle(6))
```

Comment: And the issue is..? I suspect it would be good to *actually* return a string, with line breaks, instead of an array of strings. There is a method called `Array.join` which would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `triElements.join("\n");` in your return statement

Comment: Thanks, and as @Niels said, you can also get ride of array as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an array and not the triangle in a single string. I think you are over thinking it by using an array to store the result, just use a string like in this example:

```
function triangle(numOfLayers) {
    var result = '';
    var symbol = '#';
    var layer = '';
    var lineBreak = '\n';
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfLayers; i++) {
        layer += symbol; // add one symbol to last layer
        result += layer + lineBreak; // append an extra line to the result
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(triangle(6))
```

Comment: Ah...I see. This is an amazing learning session for me. Thank you so much.